# more specific about sending json with utf8 to iphone from php server

Tags: php, objective-c, json

We have php server that sends json string in utf-8 encoding.
Im responsible for the iphone app that get the data.

I want to be sure that on my side everything is correct :

```
//after I downlad the data stream :

NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.m_dataToParse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//here the data is shown correctly in the console

NSLog(@"%@",content);

SBJsonParser *_parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];

NSDictionary *jsonContentDictionary = [_parser objectWithData:self.m_dataToParse];

//here, when i printer values of array IN array, i see \u454 u\545 \4545 format. any ideas why ?

for(id key in jsonContentDictionary)

{

NSLog(@"key:%@, value:%@,key, [ jsonContentDictionary objectForKey:key]);

}
```

im using the latest version of json library :
https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

There is problem is the iphone side ? (json parser ? ) or in the php server ?

just to be clear again :
1.on the console, before json, the string looks o.k
2.after doing json, the array in array values are in the format of `\u545 \u453 \u545`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. 
A possible reason of the issue, and you must investigate it with your content provider (the server that sends the json to you), is that even if the whole json string is correctly encoded as utf-8 (remember: the json text is a sequence of character and so an encoding must be specified), it may happen that some or all of the text content (that is the values of the single objects contained in the json message) has been originally encoded in another format, typically this is html-encoding (iso-8859) especially when particular characters are used (e.g. cyrillic or asian). Now the json framework by default decodes all data as utf-8, but if there is a coding mismatch between the utf-8 characters and the iso-8859 (just to remain in the example) then the only way to transform them in utf-8 is to use the \u format. This happens quite often, especially when php scripts extract the info from html pages, which are usually encoded using iso-8859. And consider also that iOS is not able to convert the whole set of iso-8859 characters to unicode (e.g.: cyrillic).
So possible solutions are:
- do a content encoding of texts server side (iso-8859 --> utf-8)
- or if this is not possible, then it's up to you to recognize the \uxxx sequences coming more often from your content provider and replace them with the corresponding utf-8 characters.